# How to send a parameter which is dictionary in Postman

Tags: postman

I have just started using **Postman** for testing my API.
I am able to send list of request parameters, but could not figure out how will I send a parameter which is a dictionary,

say my request  has two different parameters, first is property, and the structure of property is something like `"ptype":"residential","mtype":"requirement","dtype":"sale","category":"multistoryapt","city":"Gurgaon,Mumbai"`

How can I send these parameters together ?
I have explored on internet and there are ways of sending an array but not a dictionary.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a post request?

If so, are all your parameters in your API's controller strings?

Comment: yaa, It is a post request. I exactly don't knowwhat API's controller strings is? is it the parameters we are sending in URL or normal request parameters ?

Comment: By chance are you using ASP.NET MVC 4 to build your API? 
(only asking because it's very common)

Comment: No, I am using Node.js

Comment: Okay not as familiar with node.js, but right now what you're doing is you're sending a bunch of strings as the inputs for your post request. 

You're telling postman, I have an input parameter called "ptype", and I want to assign it as "residential". 

This won't work unless you really do have all the inputs as a string in your Post method. You can either change this in the method itself by making all the input parameter requirements strings and then formatting them into an array in this method. Or you could use the syntax for arrays with { }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could send data as raw body with the Content-Type application/json, this way it's up to you how the data is structured.

Comment: I think what he's looking for is the syntax of sending an array as a parameter rather than multiple strings. 

From what I've gathered, I believe his Post Method has a parameter that takes an array. I don't use postman so i'm not entirely sure.I presume it's the same just like {"string1", "string2"} as the values for the key? Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Andre : Thanks for suggesting, I figured it out.

Comment: @KabirPeshawaria postman supports `form-data` `x-www-form-urlencoded` by default (with extra input formulars). For everything else there is always `raw` and `binary` for inputs.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to send it in the `application/json` format then the body should look like this:

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
}
```

For a comprehensive resource on how to serialise JSON go to http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you cannot send it with json, here is how we send dictionaries in the form:

```
object[ptype], object[mtype], object[dtype], object[category], object[city]
```

Answer (score 3):

I cam across this topic as I have a parameter

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Customer { get; set; }
```

for my REST API and I wanted to test it with Postman. Unfortunately I didn't find any quick help for how to send a Dictionary using Postman. After trying around some combinations this is what worked for me

```
Customer[0].Key:name
Customer[0].Value:Testname
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this:

POST Request in Postman:

Content-Type: Json/Application

```
{
   "IsManual":true,
   "platform":"IOS",
   "barcodeList":{"1":"DSSDsdsdsas","2":"DSSDsdsdsas"},
   "Client":"Cliente1",
   "ScanDate":"2018-10-16T17:03:02.2347052-03:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- ****Match the name of your dictionary and Request body dictionary name.****

Suppose ,

```
 Dictionary<string,string> randomName = new Dictionary<string,string(){{"key1","value1"} ,{"key2","value2"}};

so , your request for PostMan should be:

{
    "randomName " : { "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar problem with yours and solved it by using the `form-data` input type of POSTMAN. I have the following GET mapping for my Java spring RestController:

```java
@GetMapping("/card")
    public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<EntityModel<CardDto>>> aggregateGetCards(
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> filterParams,
            @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE_IDX) @Min(0) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(name = "items_in_page", defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) @Min(1)
            Integer pageSize,
            @RequestParam(name = "sort_by_field", defaultValue = DEFAULT_SORT_BY_FIELD) @NonNull @NotBlank
            String sortByField,
            @RequestParam(name = "sort_order", defaultValue = DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER) @NonNull
            SortOrder sortOrder
            ){
.
.
.
}
```

`filterParams` is a `Map` (the Java equivalent of a dictionary) that in JSON format would look something like:

```json
{
     "name" : "some_user@useremail.com",
     "color" : "#FH90J7"
     "creatingUser" : "some_other_user@otheruseremail.com"
     .
     .
     .
}
```

I can pass the pagination parameters (`"page"`, `"items_in_page"`, etc.) just fine from the `Params` tab of POSTMAN:

[image: The Params tab of my POSTMAN]

While for the `filterParams` `Map`, I have to use the `form-data` tab, for example:

[image: The "form data" tab of my POSTMAN.]

You might want to be a bit more consistent with snake_casing and camelCasing than I have been :)